# Joomla export Excel (.xls or .csv)

Tags: php, joomla, phpexcel

How to export the Excel (`.csv` or `.xls`) variable from database? It does not work to insert variable from database e.g. `$temp` (it can echo the single value from variable)

```
  require_once(JPATH_LIBRARIES . '/phpexcel/library/PHPExcel.php');
  require_once(JPATH_LIBRARIES.'/phpexcel/library/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php');$query = "SELECT referreid,insert_date,datareference FROM `miqi_alpha_userpoints_details` WHERE `referreid`='$referrerid' AND `enabled`='1' ORDER BY `insert_date` DESC";
  $db->setQuery( $query );
  $results = $db-> loadAssocList();
  $temp = $results[0]['referreid'];
  $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1','123');
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B1',$temp);
  header('Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8'); //mime type
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="abc.csv"'); //tell browser what's the file name
  header('Cache-Control: max-age=0'); //no cache
  $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'CSV');
  $objWriter->save('php://output');
  exit;
```

Comment: I've cleaned your question up a bit, but I'm still not clear what you're asking. Please read your question carefully and ensure that you've included enough detail. The [ask] page has great tips about asking questions effectively.

Comment: You can create a .csv document type.